# Why does the system display "No main method found in project."

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I run Code A in https://play.kotlinlang.org/, it's good.

But Code B can't be run, it display error "No main method found in project.", why?

**Code A**

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
  launch {    
     delay(300L) 
     println("A1")        
  }    

  launch {    
     delay(100L) 
     println("A2")        
  } 

  println("A3")
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
  launch {    
     delay(300L) 
     println("A1")        
  }    

  launch {    
     delay(100L) 
     println("A2")        
  } 


}
```

Comment: Code A doesn't work: `Unresolved reference: runBlocking
Unresolved reference: launch
Unresolved reference: delay
Unresolved reference: launch
Unresolved reference: delay` Please add the full actual code you used.

Comment: Change Code B `runBlocking` statement to `runBlocking<Unit>`. It doesn't work because it's returning a Job.